# KeyError when adding layer to WebMap with add_layer in Python ArcGIS API

Tags: python, api, addlayer, keyerror

I'm a GIS student and in my school project I am trying to add a layer to a Web Map.  I am using Python ArcGIS API in Jupyter.
I found the layers I wish to add with content.search and have them in a list of tuples along with their titles.  Then I have this code to add the layers:

```py
for item, title in featurelist:
    print(item)
    wm.add_layer(item, options = {"title":title})
```

It prints the item and then the `Key Error`:

```
<Item title:"Boat Ramps of Lake Travis by CR" type:Shapefile owner:cynthia.roush@g.austincc.edu>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py in __getitem__(self, k)
   7004         try:
-> 7005             return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
   7006         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'layers'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-120a1e45a0bb> in <module>
      1 for item, title in featurelist:
      2     print(item)
----> 3     wm.add_layer(item, options = {"title":title})

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\mapping\_types.py in add_layer(self, layer, options)
    318             if not self._extent:
    319                 self._extent = layer.extent
--> 320             if hasattr(layer, 'layers'):
    321                 if layer.type == 'Feature Collection':
    322                     options['serviceItemId'] = layer.itemid

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py in __getattribute__(self, name)
   6976     def __getattribute__ (self, name):
   6977         if name == 'layers':
-> 6978             if self['layers'] == None or self['layers'] == []:
   6979                 try:
   6980                     with _DisableLogger():

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py in __getitem__(self, k)
   7007             if not self._hydrated and not k.startswith('_'):
   7008                 self._hydrate()
-> 7009             return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
   7010     #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   7011     @property

KeyError: 'layers'
```

Answer (score 2):

After I put the layer on AGOL with content.add, I needed to use the publish method of the resulting item such as:

```
published_service = item.publish()
```

Only then could I add the layer to a web map.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have an item in your content with the same name as the title of the item you want to add.

My guess is that there is a service definition with that name. You can avoid the error by using `item_type='Feature Layer'` within your search.